# Changing controller's action in the click into a link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have done an asp.net mvc application  and i  have this problem :
In a view i have the following snippet:

```
<section id="loginForm" >


    <form action="/Account/Login" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Formulaire de connexion</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Pseudo)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pseudo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Pseudo)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>


        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Se connecter"  />
        <a href="@Url.Action("Reinitialiser", "Account")" style="color:blue">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>  
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</section>



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Normally when i click into the link `<a href="@Url.Action("Reinitialiser", "Account")" style="color:blue">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>` it redirect me to the action `Reinitialiser` in the `Account` controller:

```
  [AllowAnonymous]

        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
             Upload.Models.LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
            IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostEntry.AddressList[0];
             if(model.IsIp_Banned(ipAddress.ToString()))return View("Banissement");                                                                               


        }


        public ActionResult Reinitialiser() {
            return View();
        }
```

But if i click into the link it redirect me to the action `Login`.

Why this happens? how can i correct it?

Comment: You don't have the `AllowAnonymous` attribute on the `Reinitialiser` method, is it needed?

Comment: i deleted it and i have this url then `http://localhost:59728/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fReinitialiser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution i just delete `[Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]`  and `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes and it is works

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have the [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the Reinitailiser method?

Comment: i deleted it and i have this url then `http://localhost:59728/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fReinitialiser`